# installation file corrupted from install4j

Tags: installation, corrupt, install4j

install4j's multiplatform installer has been working great for years. Now out of the blue we are getting an error popup dialog that `The installation file is corrupted. If it is a download please try again.` It has installed about 19MB of 164MB and the last file it didn't write was a small jar that has been in the build for some time now.

We get this error when running the full installer right after it is built as a test. We are also building several 'companion' applications with all the same files just different start up options and its installer run fine.

We are using install4j in batch mode:
install4j version: 5.0.8 (build 5311)

Thanks.

Comment: Have you tried this with the current release (5.1.2)?

Comment: I was trying to avoid this only because it introduces new unknowns, but we will try that next. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Are you running it on the latest Mac OS? If so then this is because of the latest Gatekeeper "feature" of Apple and you need to sign your code: http://support.apple.com/kb/HT5290